# How to handle onClick on a DIV outside the controls on the DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DIV with id settingsDiv with several combo boxes, I like to close the window if I click somewhere in the window expect on a combo box of course.
I use the following html code:

```
<div id="settingsDiv" onClick="javascript:closeSettings()">
<form id="settings">
Font size:
<select id="fontSizeFactor" size="1">    
  <option value="2.0">200%</option>
  <option value="1.75">175%</option>
  <option value="1.5">150%</option>
  <option value="1.25">125%</option>
  <option selected value="1.0">100%</option>
  <option value="0.75">75%</option>
  <option value="0.5">50%</option>
</select><br />
…
</div>
```

and this javascript function:

```
function closeSettings() {
$('#settingsDiv').hide();
  }
```

The problem is that closeSettings is also called if I click on a combo box.
How should I change the code so that closeSettings is only called if I click in the window outside the combo boxes?

To see this window open [this page](http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Vecht_Arien/) and click the settings button in the upper right corner (You can now close the window only by clicking again on the settings window).

Comment: there are several ways to do so. the easiest however would be to add a div that has the size of the whole window behind the settings window. this way you could catch clicks to it and close it aswell as the settings window.

Comment: additional you can gray the background out by using that div. so you have multiple benefits from such an option.

Comment: It is a pity, but your solution is not working. I did implement your solution in [this page](http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Vecht_Arien/) as follows:
<div id="AroundsettingsDiv" onClick="javascript:closeSettings()()">
    <div id="settingsDiv">
    <form id="settings">
    Font size:
and
    function closeSettings() {
      $('#AroundsettingsDiv').hide();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can be used like this:
Just get the event of the clicked div to check whether its child clicked or div self.

You need to change this line also

```
<div id="settingsDiv" onClick="javascript:closeSettings()">
```

with this line

```
<div id="settingsDiv" onClick="javascript:closeSettings(event)">
```

..
Your update Function is:

```
function closeSettings(event) {
   var id=event.target.id;//getting the clicked element id.
  if(id=="settingsDiv")
    $('#settingsDiv').hide();
  }
```

Comment: Yes that works!! I had to make a small correction: instead of      if(id=="settingsDiv") I had to use    if (id=="settings").You can see it on [this page](http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Vecht_Arien/) <br>Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try these methods in your function when you click on the combo box `event.stoppropagation(); event.preventdefault();` maybe it will work.